# MongoDB C# - Update timestamp when inserting in a list

Tags: mongodb

Let's assume this:

```
class A
{
    DateTime MyTime;
}

class B
{
    List<A> MyData;
}
```

I have a MongoDB collection with objects B.

I have an update function that adds an object A into the MyData list in an object B.

So, my update goes like this, in pseudo code.

```
A.MyTime = DateTime.UTCNow;
B.MyData.Add(A); (using AddToSet update method)
```

I would like to know if I can do an update statement to get the server to set its time rather than using the client's time.

---

Some clarification:

I would add the A object like this:

```
A MyAObject = new A();
A.MyTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
[...] Builders<B>.Update.AddToSet(_ => _.MyData, MyAObject);
```

But I would like the line setting the time to be done on the server to reflect server time, so the object needs to be modified by the server and then inserted in the MyData list of an object B.

Comment: Not that clear what you are asking here. There is a [`$currentDate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/) update modifier but it's usage is for a specific field path rather than for addition to a "set". Also it's main function is for use with "multi" updates, where instead of providing a "fixed" timestamp for all matched documents, the actual time of modification would be used. So what isn't really clear here is both *"Why do you think you need this in an array?"*, and also *"Given the class definition is such an entry really unique?"*

Comment: The second point there is a "set" is unique to it's components. Therefore if you have a class with "properties" on it, then **any** variation in those properties is "unique" and therefore a new "set" member. Perhaps you actually mean *"an array of dates"* as opposed to *"an array of objects with a date property"*

Comment: The AddToSet in Mongo's C# driver is essentially a List.add(); so what I want is to change a field in the object I submit to put the server time in it and then add that modified object in a list in a mongo record.
Let me update the question to clarify